# Inserting 2 different integers to 2 different arrays simultaneously in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I am facing an issue regarding entering numbers to 2 different arrays using only one for loop.

To begin with,I initialized array0 as `int age[N]` and array1 as `float pay[M]`,
defining them at the start with `#define N 10`,`#define M 10`,(I was asked to do so ,so I cannot really write them in any other way).

Using two "for" loops I successfully manage to insert the values.Then I did two major attempts to combine them.

One with

```
b=0; 
for(i=0,i<N,i++){
    b++; 
    scanf(" %d",&age[i]);
    scanf(" %f",&pay[b]);
}
```

the result was that 9/10 elements of each array was listed fine except 2 of them which had unexpected values.

The second was

```
i=b=0; 
while(i<N && b<M)
{
    i++;
    b++; 
    scanf(" %d",&age[i]);
    scanf(" %f",&pay[b])
}
```

which only had listed the `age[0]` element with wrong value.

So my question is can I really combine the as detailed below for loops?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
#define M 10

int main()
{
    int age[N]; 
    float pay[M];       
    int i,b,; 
    for(b=0;b<M;b++){
        scanf(" %f",&pay[b]);}

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %d",&age[i]);
        if(age[i]<18 || age[i]>=67)
        {
            do{     
                printf("Please enter a number equal or greater than 18 and less than 67,as people under 18 are considered minors and from 67 and above eligible for retirement\n");
                scanf(" %d",&age[i] ); }while(age[i]<18 || age[i]>=67);
            
        }
        
    }
```

I am at a novice level so please excuse me for any mistakes,also I am more than happy to study other solutions using different methods in case you cant really combine those 2 for loops.

Comment: Because `N==M` there is no need for any `b` counter. `for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { scanf(" %f", &pay[i]); scanf(" %d", &age[i]); }` This will only work if you alternate the numbers when entering them (pay age pay age....)

Comment: your `main` is not implemented fully and for `do{ }while();` `while` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

As Johnny Mopp said, the only reasonable way to combine these loops is if you can alternate. I feel that using two loops is a perfectly reasonable thing to do here otherwise. That said, if you absolutely must combine the two, take advantage of the fact that N == M to use one loop and still do these actions serially, by waiting for the first M iterations before reading into age[]. Pretty ugly, but it should work. Quick pseudocode:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (M + N); ++i) {
    if (i < M) {
       scanf(" %f",&pay[i]);
    }
    else {
       scanf(" %d",&age[i - N]);
       do ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Johnny's Mopp suggestion into my code and It works as I wanted in the first place.So `for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { scanf(" %f", &pay[i]); scanf(" %d", &age[i]); }` seems to be the answer I was looking for.

Thanks for your time and help,I do appreciate it.